# NServiceBus DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers keeps retrying forever

Tags: nservicebus

Using NServiceBus 4.6.1 and when I call Bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers(); the message goes to the corresponding ravenDB database with a timeout, and so after 1 minute the message is retried again and again forever.

Shouldn't this function just retry the number of times in the app.config and then move it to the error queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was calling Bus.Defer with 1 minute, before calling Bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers();

That was the reason.